# Acceder a la cámara Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, cámara

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar es que necesito acceder al la cámara de **iPhone** en **Xamarin iOS** o en su defecto a la `galería de imágenes`.

Comment: Por favor muestra lo que has intentado. Si no has intentado nada, entonces te pido que busques en alguna parte algún tutorial, lo sigas y si tienes problemas entonces muestres dónde están los problemas particulares y que te ayudemos sobre eso. Si tienes esta información, entonces te recomiendo que selecciones [edit] y agregues toda la información relevante para comprender mejor tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar Dependency Injection para acceder a la cámara en IOS por Xamarin o ..

Puedes utilizar un plugin que te ahorra el dependency injection y te da acceso a la cámara en Android, IOS, y Windows.

Uno de los más conocidos se llama **MediaPlugin**, del famoso James Montemagno. Yo ya lo utilicé para un proyecto y funcionó de maravilla. Lo encuentras en https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin.

En la misma página, están las instrucciones de paso por paso cómo hacerlo.

Comment: gracias por la pronta respuesta por casualidad conoces un ejemplo del que me pueda guiar. de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: En la pagina del plugin:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin Estan las instrucciones  de paso por paso como hacerlo. No hay pierde. Saludos !

Comment: Gracias amigos por sus respuestas